# Gem bundles error stops metasploit from starting on my iDevice

Tags: iphone, ruby, rubygems, bundles, metasploit

hope you all doing good,

so my problem is that I can't run metasploit on my iPhone and it's kind of frustrating since I'm sure I followed the installation steps carefully. 
When I type "ruby msfconsole" it says that Metasploit requires the bundler gem to be intalled. So I searched for it and found that "gem install bundles" should fix it, but It didn't! 
And here's a screenshot of the whole process:

[image]

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Got a link to the installation steps you followed? might help diagnose the issue.

Comment: Thanks for replying Mike, I searched for further steps I can take as a result I updated the rubygem source list and now it leads me to another problem, it says "connection refused -recvform(2)".. I asked about it again and they told me it may be some kind of proxy issue but I'm not using any proxies and I can reach http://rubygems.org server with no problem.. Here's the steps I followed: https://securitystreet.jive-mobile.com/#jive-document?content=%2Fapi%2Fcore%2Fv2%2Fposts%2F5849   And here's a screenshot of the terminal,   [img]http://s9.postimg.org/4wuppiiwr/image.jpg[/img]  thank you!

Answer (score -1):

i know this issu i had it my self but when jou see the error it says easy sead that the ruby code doesent get the encryption that happand most of the time on iphone i think that you downloaded ruby from cydia but the ruby 1.9.3 version from cydia is broken what jou can do is go to cydia and install the metasploit pakkage from there after install go back in the terminal and go to whear it is i guase usr or var jou will find it and start it from the metasploit map it will work but it is not the latest version because the version 4 wont work on iphone!!!!!!
3 does.
i hope that this works and jou cant fix ruby that bug dit i dont fix :(
sorry for bad english.